# SQL Query CASE with SUM and Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables Expenses and Employee. I would like to get the total amount of expenses per employee, and the total amount of expenses that have been refunded. The refunded is defined as 1 and non refunded as 0.

At the moment, my query returns the following, but should have added up the values per employee and return only one row:

```
select  distinct(emp.employeeid) as EmpID, sum(ex.amount) as TotalExpenses,
(select SUM( ex.amount ) where ex.Refunded =1) as refunded,
(select SUM( ex.amount ) where ex.Refunded =0) as notrefunded
from Expenses ex 
left outer join  Employee emp
on ex.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID 
group by  emp.employeeid,ex.amount, ex.Refunded  

48  10.00   10.00   NULL
48  16.00   NULL    16.00
49  2.00    2.00    NULL
49  10.00   NULL    10.00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a strange use of subqueries, and you don't need `distinct` when using `group by`.  I think this is the query you want:

```
select emp.employeeid as EmpID, sum(ex.amount) as TotalExpenses,
       sum(case when e.Refunded = 1 then ex.amount else 0 end) as refunded,
       sum(case when e.Refunded = 0 then ex.amount else 0 end) as notrefunded
from Employee emp left outer join
     Expenses ex 
     on ex.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID 
group by emp.employeeid;
```

Note:  I switched the order of the `left outer join`.  You are grouping by the employee id.  It seems unlikely that expenses would be for an non-existent employee.  And the aggregation was by `emp.employeeid` anyway, suggesting that you really do expect a match.

Answer (score 2):

@Gordon Linoff's answer is the ideal solution. However, it doesn't address some mistakes made in your initial query.

1. `Distinct` is a clause for the `select` statement, not a function. It always applies to all of the returned fields.
2. When using correlated sub-queries (i.e. sub-queries that appear in the column list), you need to connect the sub-query to the main query and query the table separately. As written, you're getting the `sum` for only the value found in that row. To do this correctly, it would need to be something like this:

   ```
   (select SUM( ex2.amount ) 
      from Expenses ex2 
     where ex2.Refunded =1 
           and ex2.employeeid = e.ex2.employeeid) as refunded
   ```